# Regex for Curly braces Number Curly brace ({n}) in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a simple regex , but i don't know where am I going wrong . I need to check whether a string has a curly brace number curly brace.

Eg: Consider the string
    Swapstream{2} - true
    Swapstram - false

```
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("\\{[0-9]\\}");
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(input);
if(matcher.matches())
{\\logic}
```

Also I tried writing \d instead of [0-9] , still the string is not matching.
Please help ! . Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("\\{\\d+\\}");
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(input);
if(matcher.find()) {
    /// match found
}
```

i.e. use `\d+` to allow more than one digit between `{` and `}` and more importantly use `Matcher.find()` instead of `Matcher.matches()` which expects to match complete input line.

Comment: Does the left curly brace have any meaning on regex that it needs to be escaped? The right brace doesn't on my machine.

Comment: Yes left curly bracket is used for limiting quantifier such as `a{5,9}`

Answer (score 2):

The `matches()` method only returns true if the entire string is a match for the regular expression.  You should use the `find()` method of the `Matcher` class instead.